# Fill data frame with each iteration using for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration

I have a very simple query, but not able to get my desired result.

Below table is just an example

```
id  label   val
1   a   2
2   a   4
3   c   5
4   b   4

t<-read.table("testdata.txt", header=T)

clist <- c("a", "b")
for(j in clist) {
lab <-subset(t, label==j) # The example is just an illustration, I do not require 'subset' in my original problem, yet I get a big data frame in each iteration.
}
```

After each iteration, the output is an data frame.

```
iteration with label "a"
1   a   2
2   a   4
```

Iteration with label "b"

```
4   b   4
```

Final output should be

```
1   a   2
2   a   4
4   b   4
```

How to fill variable "lab" in each iteration.

Comment: If you are using a `for` loop you are almost certainly using an inefficient solution. In your example I'd just use `t[t$label %in% clist,]`. You should give an example that matches your real usecase better. Btw. don't call an object `t`. That's the name of an important function and could make reading your code confusing.

Comment: A typical R way to avoid such a loop would probably be something like `lab <- lapply(c("a", "b"), function(x) subset(t, label==x) )`. This will result in a list of data frames, which you can bind using `do.call(rbind, lab)`.